# how to explain DataLoader changing input dimensions

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, torch, torchvision, pytorch-dataloader

I am using Dataloader to read my dataset with contains pairs

```
train_dataset[0][1].shape

torch.Size([3, 128, 128])

train_dataset[0][0].shape

torch.Size([3, 128, 128])
```

```
train_data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    dataset=train_dataset,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    num_workers=0,
    pin_memory=False,
    drop_last=True,
)
```

```
data_iter = iter(train_data_loader)
batch, _ = next(data_iter)
print(f"Dimensions of the pairs in train_data_loader:{batch[0][0].shape}, {batch[0][1].shape}")
```

Dimensions of the pairs in train_data_loader:torch.Size([128, 128]), torch.Size([128, 128])

why DataLoader is changing the dimensions? how to fix it ?

I read the Dataloader description and I asked chatgpt but i could not find the answer

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the bold parts here are not the problem?

**batch, _** = next(data_iter)
print(f"Dimensions of the pairs in train_data_loader:{**images_batch**[0][0].shape}, {**images_batch**[0][1].shape}")

Comment: Yes, I am sure this is not the problem. It was a typo the the question formulation only